# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

Tags: graph-databases, apache-age, wails

I'm running the Apache [AGE-viewer-Go](https://github.com/apache/age/tree/ageviewer_go) Project
using the `wails build` command to run the Desktop application in Ubuntu 22.04.

I'm using `wails version v2.4.1` and `go version go1.20.4`

when I run the command `wails dev` in age-viewer folder of the project it runs fine and opens the project on localhost:SOMEPORT

but I need to run the desktop application for that I run the following command:

`wails build`

it makes a file myproject in [Project - Folder]/age-viewer/build/bin/ directory as shown in the following image:

[image: Image showing the output of wails build command]

but when I run the `./myproject` command [Project - Folder]/age-viewer/build/bin directory it gives my following error:

[image: Image showing error]

`I'm running these command in vscode terminal`

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow some steps to run this First of All Go to Age-viewer and then go to frontend and

```
npm install react-router-dom
npm install
```

after that come back to Age-viewer and then

```
wails dev
```

make sure you have started the backend by simply navigating to backend folder

```
go run .
```

Backend will be running on Port: 8080

Then you can test all these on PostMan

http://localhost:8080/connect

Comment: the wails dev command is running file but when I run wails build it makes a new file named myproject when I run that file that gives me an error.